# Turn off warning/notification

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word, template

Whenever I create a new document in the document library I now get this warning:
[image: SharePoint warning]

I cannot find a way to turn this off and the document library is set to always load from a template. This warning did not show up a few months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with MS support the workaround I got from them is to use a .docx file as the template for the document library and not a .dotx file. This warning is actually a bug on their end and they do not have an ETA on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use the default document template in the classic experience to add new documents as follows:

[image]

It's by design that it can't convert Word content type file templates to the correct .docx format when you use "New Document" button.

As a workaround, I suggest you use "Create a new file" button to add new document without template alert in classic experience.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the "New" drop down button in the modern experience to avoid this issue.

[image]

Comment: I have always used the modern/new experience and I am still getting this issue. It only started happening very recently.